# Create PDF on Azure blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create PDF on Azure blob. My code as below. I am getting issue with PDF create on blob. I am not able to create PDF getting Filestream is not supported.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("Chapter1_Example1.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));


            var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
            container.SetPermissions(permissions);
            string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("rewhizzdocuments/{0}", "helloworld.pdf");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
            blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            blob.UploadFromStream(fs);


            doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FileStream` is mainly used for manipulating files and since you're interested in creating PDF documents on the fly, may I suggest you use `MemoryStream` instead.

Take a look at the sample code below which makes use of `MemoryStream`:

```
    private static void CreatePdf()
    {
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("pdftest");
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            }
            var byteArray = ms.ToArray();
            var blobName = "hello-world.pdf";
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            blob.UploadFromByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
    }
```

If you still want to use `FileStream`, another thing you could do is save the file on the disk and the make use of `UploadFromFile` method on `CloudBlockBlob` to upload that file.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for reply and its work for itextsharp version 5.5.6.0 but I am using 4.1.2.0 so I am getting "'iTextSharp.text.Document': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable" error.

Comment: I don't even see this version on Nuget page :( - https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/. One thing you could try is get rid of `using` block and call doc.Close() method immediately after doc.Add() method.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, Its Work ! Now I want to add add image from one of my blob so how can I do that. Could not found anything for it.

Comment: You may want to post this as another question IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Please call doc.Close() first, and then blob.UploadFromFile("Chapter1_Example1.pdf").

Another possible solution is: call doc.Close() first, and set fs.Position = 0L, finally blob.UploadFromStream(fs). (It might not be a valid solution if doc.Close() will automatically trigger the disposal of FileStream, I can't make sure since I'm not familiar with iText.